# How to confirm data at rest encrypted by MariaDB?

Tags: database, encryption, mariadb, mariadb-10.3

I am using MariaDB's Data at rest encryption.

When firing the select query I can see the data as decrypted. After studying further this is the correct behavior.

But how do I even ensure that the data is even protected?
How do I prove it to other people?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Verifying MariaDB 10.1 encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33817877/verifying-mariadb-10-1-encryption)

Answer (score 1):

Your binary data folder can be found here:

mysql> show variables like 'datadir';

There you will find the raw files. If you have innodb_file_per_table on, it'll be easy to find the file that corresponds to your table.

For comparison, pick an unencrypted table. Open the binary file in a text editor (ideally a HEX editor but text editor should do). You should be able to see, among the binary markers, content of your table in plain text.

Next, open an encrypted file - there is no way you can decode it without the keyring.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux,

You can check if your database files are encrypted by running `strings` on one of the .ibd storage files.

```
$sudo strings /var/lib/mysql/db_name/table_name.ibd
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [article](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/disabling-innodb-encryption/#decryption-status) from MariaDB. Use this command:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS "Number of Encrypted Tablespaces"
FROM information_schema.INNODB_TABLESPACES_ENCRYPTION
WHERE ENCRYPTION_SCHEME != 0
   OR ROTATING_OR_FLUSHING != 0;
```

It will show the number of encrypted tables in your database

The result should look like this if some tables are encrypted:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdQgp.png)