# MariaDB - How to confirm Data at Rest has been encrypted?

Tags: encryption, mariadb, mariadb-10.5

I've just installed MariaDB 10.5.5 on Windows Server 2019 and have enabled the file_key_management plugin (keyfile is not encrypted (but will be)).  I need to provide proof that the data is in fact encrypted, and have tried the recommendations from the two other posts I found here ([First post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58901688/how-to-confirm-data-at-rest-encrypted-by-mariadb) and [second post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33817877/verifying-mariadb-10-1-encryption)), specifically using `strings C:/[path to my database data]/testdb.ibd | grep "abc"` but haven't had any success (I get Syntax errors that there's a problem and check the Documentation (which I did)).  I did check the INNODB_Tablespaces_encryption table and it's showing my table has Encryption_scheme = 1, so I'm assuming I am OK, but need to provide screenshots / proof of the encryption.  Any help or ideas would be appreciated.
Chris

Comment: Those are UNIX commands and are unlikely to work on Windows. You'll need to find a Windows version of those commands that search for printable strings in the database files.Additionally, you'll need string that is known to be in the table (e.g. insert `"Hello world"` into an encrypted table and then try to find that in the file).

Comment: Ahh - that makes sense @markusjm - thanks for your time.  Chris